# HTTPS post using Apache Commons client 3.0.1

Tags: java, xml, post, https

I need to develop an application which can send https Post to a web service in an xml format. For the basic setup I used Apache Commons client 3.0.1 tested using HTTP. But It does not support HTTPS. Is there any alternative for this Apache Commons probably with an newer version. Also for Http post I found that  setRequestBody depreciated. Is that any other alternative to do an https post. Url connection is not working with xml format data.

Comment: What error you get when you post data using https ?

Comment: @Santhosh. XML parsing error. No Request Body

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like to have a look at HTMLUNIT , its a http client for java programs http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/